# Print unmatched records between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 identical tables and need to get the unmatched records.

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

So now to get the unmatched records I can use Except

```
SELECT aamcid , Email, Telephone,  Address,FamilyMember , CitizenshipInfo FROM #table1
except
SELECT aamcid , Email, Telephone, Address,FamilyMember , CitizenshipInfo  FROM #table2
```

[image]

By looking at this output Email and Telephone don't match between 2 tables

I need now need to insert these records in 2 other tables

Exception table should have the records for any unmatched records , Exception should have list of all unmatched fields

```
 AAMCID          Exception
 12185303        Unmatched count : [Email] [phone]
 13573556        Unmatched Count : [Email]
```

And In audit table : expectedcount is the count from table1 and actualcount is the count from table2

```
 AAMCID        Section       expectedcount    actualcount
 12185303      Email          2               3
 12185303      Telephone      2               1
 13573556      Email          2               1
```

My question what is the best way to populate these 2 tables?

I am thinking in this idea (note the real table has 50 columns) but I am sure they may be better way

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id INT IDENTITY , aamcid INT)

INSERT #t (aamcid)
SELECT  G.aamcid 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM #table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #table2) G





    DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @x INT;

SET @i = 1;
SELECT @x = MAX(id) FROM #t
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @AAMCId INT ;
DECLARE @count1 INT;
DECLARE @count2 INT;
SET @message =''

WHILE @i <= @x

BEGIN
SELECT @AAMCId = aamcid FROM #t WHERE id = @i;

SELECT @count1 = email FROM #Table1 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
SELECT @count2 = email FROM #table2 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
IF ( @count1 != @count2)
BEGIN 
SET @message = @message + '[Email]'
INSERT INTO audit VALUES (@aamcid , 'email', @count1 , @count2)
END

SELECT @count1 = Telephone FROM #Table1 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
SELECT @count2 = Telephone FROM #table2 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
IF ( @count1 != @count2)
BEGIN 
SET @message = @message + ' [Telephone]'
INSERT INTO audit VALUES (@aamcid , 'Telephone', @count1 , @count2)
END

SELECT @count1 = address FROM #Table1 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
SELECT @count2 = address FROM #table2 WHERE aamcid = @AAMCId
IF ( @count1 != @count2)
BEGIN 
SET @message = @message + ' [Address]'
INSERT INTO auditable VALUES (@aamcid , 'Address', @count1 , @count2)
END

/*Repeat for every field*/

SET @i = @i+1

INSERT INTO Exception VALUES (@aamcid , 'unmatched records : ' + @message)


END;
```

Comment: Why are you using the word "count"? I don't see where counting comes into play.

Comment: I am not sure which "count" you are talking about. @count is just a variable

Comment: By _unmatched_ do you mean (1) any row that appears in only one of the two tables and (2) any rows that have matching `AAMCID` values between tables and other coiumns that differ? Are all of the columns really `INT`? You may want to look at using a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression to compare values and output either an empty string or the column name.

Comment: @HABO ,  (2) same AAMCID and  any unmatched values between the 2 tables. Yes they all are INT

Comment: @HABO How can i use Case in my situation?

Comment: If you join mismatched rows you can assemble the list of unmatched columns using `case`, e.g. `RTrim( case when RL.Email != RR.Email then '[Email] ' else '' end + case when RL.Telephone != RR.Telephone then '[Telephone ] ' else '' end + ... )`